# How to start internet in emulator of windows?

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm using Windows 8.1 and visual studio 2013 to develop windows phone application.

I'm also using PCL to interact with Web Service

I'm using HTTPClient to call web service method and get response in JSON format

when I try to run application on emulator or physical device , appliction is not working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors please expand on your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest testing the internet connection using IE and if you can browse to internet sites. If you can browse using IE, then you might want to check your application endpoint\URL is correct.

If you have problems connecting to internet from IE, then check the WiFi connection and\or data connection on device to see if it is setup correctly. For Emulator you can follow below steps troubleshoot internet connectivity issues. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CannotconnecttoInternetdestinations